# "dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive '/home/USER/linux': No such file or directory" on installing amdgpu drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dpkg, amdgpu

trying to install amdgpu proprietary drivers ,
did a `./amdgpu-install` on the installer directory and saw the error
`dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive '/home/somguy04/linux': No such file or directory`

what i have to do to fix this?

ASUS X555DG

20.04 AMD fx-8800 + radeon r7 + radeon r8 m350dx built-in

many thanks in advance

Comment: *"trying to install amdgpu proprietary drivers"* how, exactly? Please [edit] your question to show the steps - or add a link to the instructions you are following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case, the problem was the directory path where amdgpu-install was had a space in it.  Renamed all the directories in the path to remove the spaces and it worked.